# running sipp from java

Tags: java

I am programming a Java interface for the sipp command line program. My current code is:

```
 ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("sipp", "-sn uac",
              "127.0.0.1");
        Map<String, String> environment = builder.environment();
        Process javap = builder.start();
        InputStreamReader tempReader = new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(javap.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(tempReader);
        while (true){
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if (line == null)
                break;
            System.out.println(line);
            }
```

This does not work for me thought, I have sipp environment variable set so this is not the problem. The standard output is sipp's help message. What am I doing wrong? Also I would like to know once I got sipp running is it possible to pass arguments to the processBuilder object associated with it so I can change the call rate? i.e. sipp let users change call rate by pressing + , - , * is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try breaking up the `-sn` and `uac` parameters:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("sipp", "-sn", "uac", "127.0.0.1");
```

> Also I would like to know once I got
>   sipp running is it possible to pass
>   arguments to the processBuilder object
>   associated with it so I can change the
>   call rate?

If `sipp` is expecting input from standard in, you should be able to grab an output stream (`javap.getOutputStream()`) to the process and write commands to it.  I don't know anything about `sipp` to tell you whether that's how it works, though.

Comment: Thanks  a lot for the answer that did the trick, the commands are of type "q" "+" e.t.c. so if I grab the outputStream from process and then do" String test = "q";              javap.getOutputStream().write(test.getBytes());" this should work correct?

Comment: @maxsap - Something very similar should work (I'd have to test it out to know for sure) assuming that `sipp` is expecting data from standard in.  You probably also need to call `flush` on the output stream after each write.

Comment: Yes I have forgot to write flush command, I have tried to run this a process with this command:ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(path.trim(), "127.0.0.1:5060", "-sf","scenario.xml","-i","127.0.0.1","-p","5050", "-r", "1","-m","1000000"); wich is a standard command (works dirrectly from command line) but from java when I try to run it the readline returns null so the code exits. this is really weird because other commands work fine that way, sipp is located under /usr/bin ?

Comment: found the solution, according to this forum https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=739747 you have to set this command:export TERM=xterm in bashrc in order to work.